# How do I create a "double enter" in a spoiler tag?

Tags: support

I was trying to create a "double enter" in a text, to make it more clean and easy to read (spreading the info in "topic like" text)

How can I replicate (using spoiler (`>!`) tag) the following text

---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mattis, diam id blandit aliquet, lectus odio hendrerit orci, scelerisque posuere eros ante vel dolor. Duis odio nisl, pellentesque et ullamcorper et, ultricies et mauris. Nullam tincidunt euismod diam ut dignissim.

Aenean ac tellus vitae mauris pharetra eleifend. Pellentesque feugiat semper libero, quis ultrices justo elementum vitae.

---

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus
>  mattis, diam id blandit aliquet, lectus odio hendrerit orci,
>  scelerisque posuere eros ante vel dolor. Duis odio nisl, pellentesque
>  et ullamcorper et, ultricies et mauris. Nullam tincidunt euismod diam
>  ut dignissim. 
>
>  Aenean ac tellus vitae mauris pharetra eleifend. Pellentesque feugiat
>  semper libero, quis ultrices justo elementum vitae.

Comment: Those spoiler tags do strange things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever in trouble with spoiler tags and formatting:

1. Ask yourself if you really do need to spoiler protect that much text
2. Resort to HTML.

   ```
   >! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
   >! <p>Aenean ac tellus vitae mauris pharetra eleifend.</p>
   ```

   > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
   >
   > Aenean ac tellus vitae mauris pharetra eleifend.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use double spaces to create explicit newlines on two consecutive lines:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
>
> Aenean ac tellus vitae mauris pharetra eleifend.

The code is

```
>!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  
>!  
>!Aenean ac tellus vitae mauris pharetra eleifend.
```

And each of the first two lines has two spaces at the end